# Sql Server,use a subquery to find value in one table that is not in another

Tags: sql-server

I am comparing an original table in SQL server to an Update table. I'm trying to find how many "First Numbers" have changed. As they do change in this system. But, this query seems to bring back  "First Numbers" that that are equal to both tables. What am I doing wrong?

```
select *
from   
    tblBlue
where  
    Exists (Select 'x'
            From tblRed
            Where tblRed.FirstNumber != tblBlue.FirstNumber 
              and tblRed.ID = tblBlue.ID)
```

Example data:

```
tblRed
ID  FirstNumber
1   10 
2   20
3   30
4   40

tblBlue
1   5
2   20
3   35
4   40
```

I would expect to see:

```
1   5
3   35
```

Comment: On first glance, this would look ok. Can you post some sample data and the results you would expect?

Comment: Your query works on the sample data, see [example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5c6a/1/0).  Perhaps you are selecting from `tblBlue` where you want the values from `tblRed`-- try to swap them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work (see [example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9066c/2/0).)  Could you post example data for which it's returning the wrong results?

A slightly clearer way to write it:

```
select  *
from    tblBlue new
join    tblRed old
on      new.ID = red.ID
where   new.FirstNumber <> old.FirstNumber
```

Comment: This changes the semantics significantly. For every match in `tblRed` will return a row in `tblBlue`, increasing the result size.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: The answer assumes ID is unique in either table (as it is in the example data)

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution: use a left join

```
SELECT r.*
FROM tblRed r
LEFT JOIN tblBlue b ON b.ID = r.ID AND b.FirstNumber = r.FirstNumber
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

This will return records in `tblRed` that satisfy one of two conditions: 1) the `ID` isn't even found in `tblBlue`, i.e. a new record. or 2) the IDs were found, but the numbers have changed.  Because if both the `ID` is the same and the `FirsTNumber` is the same, then `b.ID` will not be NULL, thus a match, and you can exclude it from the resultset of different values.

Comment: If you don't need records in tblRed that don't exist in tblBlue (i.e. new IDs) then prefer @Andomar's solution since INNER JOIN's are generally more efficient http://stackoverflow.com/a/15705696/1795053